# How to save workbook with a worksheet titled "X, Y, or Z...", etc. to a subfolder? Multiple variable strings?

Tags: string, vba, excel

This is a VBA code to save an Excel workbook in a "Food" folder in the workbook's directory if it has a worksheet named "Orange, Apple..."  Right now it only works if I put one food in the code.  I.e.,:

```
sName = "Orange"
```

Here is the full code:

```
Sub CheckWorksheetNames()

Dim sName As String
Dim sFound As Boolean
Dim strPath As String

strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder\Food\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

sName = "Orange" Or "Apple" Or "Broccoli" Or "Cheese"

If sName = "" Then Exit Sub
sFound = False

On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sName).Select
    If Err = 0 Then sFound = True
On Error GoTo 0

If sFound = True Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath

End If
End Sub
```

How do I get it to go through multiple variables?  I.e., if the workbook has worksheets named "Orange, Apple, Broccoli...", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop trough all sheets and check if any of them match:

```
For Each s in Sheets
  If s.Name = "Orange" Or s.Name = "Apple" Or s.Name = "Broccoli" Or s.Name = "Cheese" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPath
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

or

```
For Each s in Sheets
    Select Case s.Name
        Case "Orange", "Apple", "Broccoli", "Cheese"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPath
            Exit For
    End Select 
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CheckWorksheetNames()

    Dim sName, arrNames  '<<EDIT: removed "As String" from sName
    Dim sFound As Boolean
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder\Food\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    arrNames = Array("Orange","Apple","Broccoli","Cheese")

    For Each sName in arrNames
        If SheetExists(sName, ActiveWorkbook) Then
            strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder\" & sName & "\" & _
                      ActiveWorkbook.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
     Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Getting "Compile error: Variable not defined" at arrNames.  I think I need a "Dim arrNames as String" or something (but that's not working).

Comment: arrNames is declared above - not sure why you'd be getting that error